# Oracle unique constraint and primary key not null

Tags: oracle, constraints

Can a table have a primary key attribute and a unique constraint to another attribute?

I have the following

```
CREATE TABLE BRANCH(
BRA_CODE NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
BRA_NAME VARCHAR(15),
BRA_ADDR VARCHAR(30),
 CITY_ID NUMBER);
```

and im trying to add

```
ALTER TABLE BRANCH ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_BRANCH_NAME UNIQUE (BRA_NAME);
```

and i get the following error;

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table
```

Comment: What does `SELECT index_name FROM dba_indexes WHERE table_name = 'BRANCH';` show?

Comment: I am trying to drop it but is not letting me, The drop operation was not successful for the following reason:

`ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key` this attribute was only set to unique and is not part of the primary key, what seems to be the problem, furthermore, the constraint seems to be in an unusable state `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01502: index '1146815.BRANCH_NAME' or partition of such index is in unusable state`

Comment: Try to drop the constraint rather than the index. The index was implicitly created when creating the unique constraint. In the worst case, drop the table and recreate it. You backup the data first by copying it to a second table: `create table BACKUP_BRANCH as select * from BRANCH`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q: Can a table have a primary key attribute and a unique constraint to
>   another attribute?

A: Yes:

- A table can have no more than one primary key.
- A primary key may consist of multiple columns (a "composite primary key")
- Any column may have a "unique constraint", whether or not it's a primary key column
- A primary key is always "unique", and always has a "unique" constraint

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists
>   in the table

A: Check your schema.  You've already already got a primary key, and/or you already defined the same unique constraint.

For example:

http://www.shutdownabort.com/dbaqueries/Structure_Constraints.php

```
col type format a10
col cons_name format a30
select  decode(constraint_type,
        'C', 'Check',
        'O', 'R/O View',
        'P', 'Primary',
        'R', 'Foreign',
        'U', 'Unique',
        'V', 'Check view') type
,   constraint_name cons_name
,   status
,   last_change
from  dba_constraints
where  table_name like 'BRANCH'
order by 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can have a unique contraint apart from the primary key, but the message indicates that you already added such a constraint.