# oracle change a column to unique

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, unique-constraint

Table has been created in system this way

```
CREATE TABLE INSTANCES
(
    DM  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCEID  VARCHAR2(512)  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCENAME  VARCHAR2(64)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    HOSTNAME  VARCHAR2(32)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_INSTANCES  PRIMARY KEY  (INSTANCEID, HOSTNAME)
);
```

The new crete table statement is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE INSTANCES
(
    DM  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCEID  VARCHAR2(512)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    INSTANCENAME  VARCHAR2(64)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    HOSTNAME  VARCHAR2(32)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_INSTANCES  PRIMARY KEY  (INSTANCEID, HOSTNAME)
);
```

The differnce is INSTANCEID has UNIQUE in it. How do i Alter the table? I used the below statement and it did not work for me.

```
ALTER TABLE INSTANCES ADD CONSTRAINT ab UNIQUE ( INSTANCEID);
```

It gave an error: 
ALTER TABLE INSTANCES ADD CONSTRAINT ab UNIQUE ( INSTANCEID)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table
02261. 00000 -  "such unique or primary key already exists in the table"
*Cause:    Self-evident.
*Action:   Remove the extra key.

Please help me to Alter the table as required above. Thanks!

Here is the output of SELECT con.constraint_name, col.column_name, con.constraint_type
  FROM user_cons_columns col
    JOIN user_constraints con ON (col.constraint_name = con.constraint_name)
WHERE col.table_name = 'INSTANCES';

```
"CONSTRAINT_NAME","COLUMN_NAME","CONSTRAINT_TYPE" 
"SYS_C0016531","DM","C" 
"SYS_C0016532","INSTANCEID","C" 
"SYS_C0016533","INSTANCENAME","C" 
"SYS_C0016534","HOSTNAME","C" 
"PK_INSTANCES","HOSTNAME","P" 
"PK_INSTANCES","INSTANCEID","P" 
"SYS_C0016536","INSTANCENAME","U"
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864299/oracle-unique-constraint-and-primary-key-not-null

Comment: Strange. Is it an option to drop the table and recreate it? Or create the new table using the second DDL, then fill it with data from the orignal table and then delete the first table and change the name of the new one to match the name of the original one? Not sure what is the problem here without being able to look at the system tables myself. Please add the result of: SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name FROM all_constraints WHERE constraint_name = 'AB';

Comment: You should explicitly name your constraints.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej i will check if i can use your option of recreating table. The query SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name FROM all_constraints WHERE constraint_name = 'AB'; did not yield any result.

Comment: @DavidAldridge please let me know, how to explicitly name constraints?

Comment: Check my answer again - I've added all in-line and out-of-line possibilites of creating all kinds of named constraints from my personal cheat-sheet.

Comment: Also, if INSTANCEID is now unique, you can replace your existing primary key with that, no?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Thanks a lot! your answer helped me. I am able to Alter the table and add constraint to INSTANCEID:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already stated that INSTANCEID is supposed to be UNIQUE, so a constraint has been created.

```
CREATE TABLE INSTANCES
(
    DM  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCEID  VARCHAR2(512)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, -- UNIQUE constraint
    INSTANCENAME  VARCHAR2(64)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    HOSTNAME  VARCHAR2(32)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_INSTANCES  PRIMARY KEY  (INSTANCEID, HOSTNAME)
);
```

**Edit**: Ok, after reading your comment, try this:

```
SELECT con.constraint_name, col.column_name, con.constraint_type
  FROM user_cons_columns col
    JOIN user_constraints con ON (col.constraint_name = con.constraint_name)
WHERE col.table_name = 'INSTANCES'
  AND con.constraint_type = 'U'
;
```

It will list UNIQUE constraints and associated columns for INSTANCE table. Please check if there is a unique constraint on the INSTANCEID column (and if that constraint has no other associated columns).

Example at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43b43/6

**Edit #2**: creating named constraints, all options:

```
-- CREATE TABLE - "In Line" Constraints

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT PORT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NAME_NN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NAME_UQ UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  STATUS NUMBER CONSTRAINT PROPER_STATUS_CK
    CHECK (STATUS IN (4, 5))
);

CREATE TABLE ships (
  SHIP_ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  HOME_PORT_ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT SHIP_PORT_FK
    REFERENCES PORTS (ID)
);


-- CREATE TABLE - "Out of Line" Constraints

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT PORT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- NOT NULL constraints can not be created "Out of Line"!

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT NAME_UQ UNIQUE (NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE ports (
  ID NUMBER,
  STATUS NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT PROPER_STATUS_CK
    CHECK (STATUS IN (4, 5))
);

CREATE TABLE ships (
  SHIP_ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  HOME_PORT_ID NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT SHIP_PORT_FK FOREIGN KEY
    (HOME_PORT_ID) REFERENCES PORTS (ID)
);

-- ALTER TABLE - "In Line" Constraints

ALTER TABLE PORTS MODIFY ID
  CONSTRAINT PORT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE PORTS MODIFY NAME
  CONSTRAINT NAME_NN NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE PORTS MODIFY NAME
  CONSTRAINT NAME_UQ UNIQUE;

ALTER TABLE SHIPS MODIFY HOME_PORT_ID
  CONSTRAINT SHIP_PORT_FK REFERENCES PORTS (ID);

-- ALTER TABLE - "Out of Line" Constraints

ALTER TABLE PORTS ADD CONSTRAINT
  PORT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);

-- NOT NULL constraints can not be created "Out of Line"!

ALTER TABLE PORTS ADD CONSTRAINT
  NAME_UQ UNIQUE (NAME);

ALTER TABLE PORTS ADD
  CONSTRAINT PROPER_STATUS_CK
  CHECK (STATUS IN (4, 5));

ALTER TABLE SHIPS ADD CONSTRAINT SHIP_PORT_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (HOME_PORT_ID)
  REFERENCES PORTS (ID);
```

NOT NULL constraints cannot be create of out line.

Comment: The table INSTANCES is created as the first create statement: i.e CREATE TABLE INSTANCES
(
    DM  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCEID  VARCHAR2(512)  NOT NULL,
    INSTANCENAME  VARCHAR2(64)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    HOSTNAME  VARCHAR2(32)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_INSTANCES  PRIMARY KEY  (INSTANCEID, HOSTNAME)
);

Comment: Here i have not made it INSTANCEID UNIQUE. It has to made UNIQUE by using ALTER.

Comment: Your command listed only one row and that is : 
CONSTRAINT_NAME  COLUMN_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE
==================================
SYS_C0015550  INSTANCENAME U

Comment: Could you enclose the results of the same query without the con.constraint_type = 'U' condition?

Comment: this is the exported csv file contents of the query result "CONSTRAINT_NAME","COLUMN_NAME","CONSTRAINT_TYPE"
"SYS_C0015550","INSTANCENAME","U"

Comment: Here it is without con.constraint_type = 'U' --- "CONSTRAINT_NAME","COLUMN_NAME","CONSTRAINT_TYPE"
"SYS_C0016531","DM","C"
"SYS_C0016532","INSTANCEID","C"
"SYS_C0016533","INSTANCENAME","C"
"SYS_C0016534","HOSTNAME","C"
"PK_INSTANCES","HOSTNAME","P"
"PK_INSTANCES","INSTANCEID","P"
"SYS_C0016536","INSTANCENAME","U"

Comment: Best add the output to your orignal post.

Comment: I have posted the output in the post above. Thanks!